# CentOs VM on Proxmox hangs when rebooting

Tags: centos, boot, kvm, proxmox

I installed a VM under Proxmox 5.0.5 running CentOS 7 (Kernel 3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64).

The virtual machine boots fine, but when performing a reboot (just the command 'reboot' from SSH), it never boots.
It hangs at this message:

```
"smpboot: CPU0: Intel QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+ (fam: 06, model: 06, stepping: 03)"
```

What could be the reason or how can I debug this further?

Comment: if you record all the messages from a successful boot and the messages from a failed boot you can more easily see what the next message is supposed to be. Serial console on the virtual machine is a good choice for doing this. I am not familiar with proxmox, but if it can direct the virtual serial port to a file adding `console=ttyS0,112500n8` to the command line of the guest should get you started.